# Handy swap between mutiple buttons sprite (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have a UI, when the player opens it, he can choose between multiple heroes (these heroes are buttons). The thing is, the hero can be locked, unlocked, or already selected, depending on different stuffs. So the image/sprite that the player see will obviously not be the same. So what is the most handy way of swapping the sprites of all heroes so i keep them up to date.

I thought that having different sprites (locked/unlocked) for each heroes would be too much, and maybe superimpose unlock sprite with an other one to create the lock image would do the trick. But how do i play around with it.

Thanks in advance, my code for now will not be usefull in anyway for what i ask

Comment: and what did not work?

Comment: `button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = getSpriteByData(isUnlocked, isSelected, isWhatever);`?

Answer (score 1):

If you build your button like this in the hierachy: 
[image]

Where the ButtonHero is the acutal button and the ButtonForeground is just an image, then you can put whatever you want in front of the hero image. This way you don't have to have multiple images of the hero with something in front. 
So by changing the Foreground's Sprite, you get different results:

Default: 
[image]

Unavailable: 
[image]

Locked: 
[image]

Likewise, if you put the hero image in the foreground, you can change the background to make it look selected:

[image]

So it's just a matter of swapping out the foreground/background image.